# Custom map use Google maps or touch with an image?

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-2

I am confused what is the best route to show the map I am going to create a mobile app on android, of a map of the zoo, and I was using Google maps api with markers for each place but I am not sure if that is good enough, should I use Google maps with a tile overlay to have the image overlay the map? Then would I make each tile with items on them clickable, or have an image with on touch coordinates? What is the best route?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using javascript map API.The best way and the most generic way is to create a infobox on click of marker itself.
Its easier done than said as follows

```
function setMarker(p) {

    var title = '<div><img src="icon_header_i_focus.png" onClick = "getDetails('
            + n
            + ')" /><div id ="place" style = "height:100%;width:100%" onClick = "getDetails('

            + ')"><label for="Name">'
            + PlaceName
            + '</label><br><label for="Address">'
            + PlaceAddress
            + '</label> </div><div id= "direction" ><a  href="javascript:getDirections('

            + ')">directions</a>'
            + '</div></div>';


    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        icon : markerImage,
        map : map,
        position : pos,
        animation : google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        if (infowindow) {
            infowindow.close();
        }
        ;
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content : title,
            maxWidth : 300
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
```

Comment: I am using the android api as I mentioned but anyways I have markers not sure if it will just look messy as oppose to putting the images

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the default markers, you can always create your own marker images with [MarkerOptions.icon()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#customize_the_marker_image).

If you want to draw an image over the map you probably want [ground overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/groundoverlay) instead of [tile overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/tileoverlay) (with the former you give maps a single overlay image and location and maps takes care of the details, with the latter you need to handle dicing the image into tiles with different zoom levels).